# Where is the log for advanced Python calculator errors?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, log

There is a specific log file for Advanced Python calculator in QGIS 2.4.0? I got the tab message below point to a log file there I wasn't able to find by myself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling `QGIS Processing log` leads directly to the docs http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/log.html which explains where the log is and what information you can find in it:

[image]